# Can the enemy destroy their own distress beacon in a downed UFO mission?

Tags: xcom-2

Playing a downed UFO mission (surprisingly I've only gotten one and I'm basically at the end of the game) and I was rushing to get to the distress beacon with four turns left - we're right outside the UFO doors and I end my turn, then Bradford comes on next turn saying "looks like the beacon was destroyed" etc. but we haven't even gotten IN the UFO yet?

So I'm guessing a pod or something destroyed it, but I've never seen that happen before - I noticed that a Chryssalid popped up on the enemy turn and disappeared, is it possible they burrowed INTO the UFO and destroyed the beacon? I honestly can't figure out what just happened (though I'm not complaining)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you were near the end of the game when this happened, it is possible a Sectopod or Gatekeeper accidentally destroyed their own beacon while moving around inside the UFO. This has apparently happened to a few people, according to posts in [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/268500/discussions/0/412447524178874020/).

The original post:

> Its no wonder the aliens are losing. They allow Gatekeepers inside UFO's. It pretty funny to watch a Gatekeeper move through a UFO. It pretty much trashes everything. My team was suppose to deactivate a distress beacon. Well the Gatekeeper did that portion of the mission for me.

A response:

> Sectopods are the best for that. During patrols I've seen them walk into (through) buildings and walls, totally destroying them. Not the best unit in the world for defending a base.

Another user reported a Sectopod doing this in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/46c8g1/psa_if_you_dont_get_to_the_distress_beacon_before/):

> Sometimes the aliens will even do it for you. Why they let Sectopods inside I'll never know, but they wreck [things] with every step.

Comment: I honestly forgot that Gatekeepers could do that - makes sense as I did actually see a Gatekeeper during that mission - I guess it destroyed the beacon while out of my line of sight. Less work for me! :D

Comment: @TaiM. Glad I could help!